# change textbox border style at runtime

Tags: html, textbox, styles, border

change textbox border style at runtime:

I have tried this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
       alert("hello");
       document.getElementById("emailid").border.style="1px solid green";
       document.getElementById('emailid').border.style="1px solid green";
    }
    <script>

    <td>Email:</td><td> <input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" value="" onblur="validate();"  maxlength=125 /><br></td>
```

It its showing me alert box but the border of textbox is not changing
    help with a working tested code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
document.getElementById("emailid").style.border = "1px solid green";
document.getElementById("emailid").style.border = "1px solid green";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("emailid").border.style = "1px solid green";
document.getElementById("emailid").border.style = "1px solid green";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your end script tag is `<script>` not `</script>` - which may be affecting things.  Also I'd highly recommend you get JQuery or some other library as using them removes any cross browser inconsistencies (and makes the code you have to write shorter).

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this code

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    alert("hello");
   document.getElementById('emailid').style.border="1px solid green";
}
</script>
```